# cocoAspell + Emacs 24 + Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: ispell

Having trouble configuring emacs 24 on Mac OS X to work with cocosAspell.

Installed MacTex dist. with success;
Installed AUCTex through emacs package manager;
Downloaded and installed the brazilian portuguese dic. for Aspell: aspell6-pt_BR-20090702-0;
tried to config my .emacs files reading a lot of sources but none worked.
Does anyone uses multi languages configurations like this? How do you set up your .emacs file?

My objective is to use both english and brazilian portuguese dicts.

Please! need help with this.

Comment: How about installing just the regular Aspell built on OSX, instead of "cocoAspell", and then use the regular Aspell dictionaries for English and Portuguese"?  Here is a link to an example that I use to switch between Aspell dictionaries of English and Spanish, as well as my own personal dictionaries for each language -- this example contemplates that the generic version of Aspell is already installed and working properly:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551890/2112489

Comment: @lawlist thanks for the help. I removed cocoAspell and installed the homebrew spell package with en and pt_BR dictionaries: $ `brew install aspell --with-lang-en --with-lang-pt_BR`. I will test from emacs right now and will let you know if it's working.

Comment: @lawlist Yeah! now it's working like a breeze. Both languages are available inside emacs now.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by removing cocoAspell and installing aspell with homebrew.

`brew install aspell --with-lang-en --with-lang-pt_BR`

check your installed dicts:

`aspell dump dicts`

remembering that i had to manually remove cocoAspell installation — but brew install reminds you the files conflicting with the new install.